# Scala REPL shows nothing when I type functions

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, read-eval-print-loop

When I type functions in Scala REPL in IntilliJ it shows nothing while it supposed to show return value (I think)
here is a function I use to calculate grades then decides whether it's bigger than five or not because there can't be grade higher than five

```
 def overallGrade(project: Int, exam: Int, join: Int) = {
    val grade = project + exam + join
    val finalGrade = min( grade,  5)
}
```

then in REPL

```
overallGrade(2,0,1)
```

it shows nothing
N.B: - I tried this with other functions but results are the same
- I tried (println) and it works
- REPL works when using maths operations
- I'm a beginner

Comment: What would you like it to show?

Comment: You are returning `Unit`. Change `val finalGrade = min(grade,  5)` to just `min(grade,  5)` to return an `Int`.

Comment: a) That's not a function, that's a method. Functions and methods are fundamentally different in Scala. b) It doesn't return anything, so what's the REPL supposed to print?

Comment: As an advice always use explicit return types for **methods**, that way you would have gotten a error message like _"Int expected found Unit"_ which would have pointed you to your problem.